# Send token CSRF Laravel per Node.js - Error CSRF Token Mismatch

Tags: node.js, laravel, api, csrf

I have an API which was developed in Laravel, and it's returning the `CSRF Token Mismatch` error when I'm consuming it in `NodeJs` with `axios`.

So I think I need to send the `token` through Node, but I'm not able to find a way to do that.

Below is the code that is consuming the API:

```js
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/messages', {
    message: 'hello test',
    id: 11
}, {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
})
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
    })
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `username` and `password` ? That should be only for [config](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config), do you have any middleware or similar in your Axios so you need to do that there ? Also, what auth provider are you using ? Fortify/Sanctum/Passport ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti In fact, I was trying to pass basic authentication to route. I'm not currently using any provider, but I can use it if that's the way. Which one would be able to authenticate with Node?

Comment: Anyone you want, it just need to have a provider behind scenes. But the 3rd argument is not being sent or anything like that, because that is a parameter for Axios config, so it is doing nothing (click the `config` link I shared in my first comment).